# Conditional Replace with Visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace, refactoring

In Visual Studio, I need to substitute a word with another, preserving the first character case.
For example I need to subsitute "Bob" with "James" and "bob" with "james" at once, and I must avoid to replace partial matches like "ob" with "james" or "James".

This can be done e.g. in Notepad++ with find:"((b)|(B))ob", replace: "(?2j:?3J)ames"; unfortunately this does not work in Visual Studio (I'm using 2015).
Is it possible to do this in Visual Studio?
Thanks.

Comment: Upvote the Case Preservation Search & Replace feature request for Visual Studio at this link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/580810/case-preserving-search-replace.html

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible with Visual Studio regex replace feature. Use Notepad++ with your current approach, or use separate regex replacements:

*Search*: `\bBob\b`
*Replace*: `James`

and then

*Search*: `\bbob\b`
*Replace*: `james`

Note that `\b` is a word boundary. If you need to replace all substrings regardless of whether `Bob` or `bob` are whole words, remove the `\b` from the patterns.